# Primitive integral solutions to $x^2+y^3=z^2$

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

The [Diophantine equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation)
$$x^2+y^3=z^2$$
has solutions $(\pm 1,2,\pm 3)$ and $(\pm 13,3,\pm 14)$.

Brown [[Int. Math. Res. Not. IMRN 2012, no. 2, 423–436; MR2876388]](https://academic.oup.com/imrn/article-abstract/2012/2/423/757814/Primitive-Integral-Solutions-to-x2-y3-z10) states that "there are infinitely many parameterized solutions with $xyz \neq 0$ and $z^2 \neq 1$ when $n \leq 5$" to the equation
$$x^2 +y^3 = z^n,$$
but does not give a reference. I am looking for a reference that catalogs all primitive solutions.

Comment: You can treat this as a special case of factoring, e.g. $Y=(z+x)(z-x)$, where you can have one of the factors (say $z-x$) be $y$ to a power. If you want everything integral, make sure the factors have the same parity. Gerhard "Difference Of Squares Is Easy" Paseman, 2017.03.14.

Comment: The last, and by far the hardest, case is $n=5$, which is solved in: J. Edwards: A Complete Solution to $X^2 + Y^3 + Z^5 = 0$,
*Journal f. d. reine und angew. Math.* (Crelle's Journal)
**571** (2004), 213-236.  (Change $(X,Y,Z)$ to $(x,y,-z)$ for your form of the equation.)  That paper should also give references for $n<5$.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies: there are references but they concern the cases when $3 \leq n \leq 5$.

Comment: The parameterization equation $x^2+y^3=z^2$ can record such.  https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1217955_the_cube_view  For $x^2+y^3=z^4$ https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1056332_diophantine_equation_with_varying_exponents   As already said - it is better for each individual degree to solve directly the equation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All solutions of the Diophantine equation $x^2-y^2=z^3$ can be found in the book "Number Theory. Volume II: Analytic and Modern Tools" (Springer Science, 2007) by Henri Cohen. Below the relevant page from this book is reproduced.

As for general case of the Generalized Fermat equation, see https://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~beuke106/Fermatlectures.pdf The generalized Fermat equation, by Frits Beukers), http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~maseap/papers/bealconj.pdf (The Generalized Fermat Equation, by Michael Bennett, Preda Mihailescu and Samir Siksek) and  http://people.math.sfu.ca/~ichen/pub/BeChDaYa.pdf (Generalized Fermat equation: a miscellany, by M.A. Bennett et al.).

[image: page 465 from the Cohen's Number Theory book (Vol. 2)]

Answer (score 4):

A warm-up:

$$ \left(\frac{s^n-t^n}2\right)^2 +\ (s\cdot t)^n\ =\ 
        \left(\frac{s^n+t^n}2\right)^2 $$

provides integer solutions for $\,\ s\equiv t \mod 2 $.

*(Sorry, I couldn't help it).*

> **REMARK**   More generally, going in the *abc* direction:
>
> $$ \left(\frac{s^m-t^n}2\right)^2 +\ s^m\cdot t^n\ =\ 
>         \left(\frac{s^m+t^n}2\right)^2 $$
>
> for $\ s\equiv t\equiv 1 \mod 2,\ $ and $\ \gcd(s\ t) = 1$.

Comment: In the remark, should it be $s \equiv t \equiv 1 \bmod 2$?

Comment: @PietroPaparella, yes, mod 2--thank you, I'll fix it.